# Replacing string in checkout summary

Tags: magento2, checkout, plugin, magento2.2.6

We have managed to modify the " Talla" Field in order to remove the "(-)" part.

What happens is once we go to next, once selected the address we want to send to, it reloads the page and the "(-)" appears again.

This is the **plugin** we have created:

```
 <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="mod_config_provider" type="Mod\PareraCustom\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin"/>
 </type>
```

**Class:**

```
class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {
        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        for($i=0; $i < count($items); $i++){
            $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
            $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteId);
            $productId = $quote->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $reference = $product->getData('sgi_reference');
            $items[$i]['sgi_reference'] = $reference;
            $options = json_decode($items[$i]['options']);
            if (count($options) > 0) {
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $option->value = str_replace('(-)', '', $option->value);
                }

                $items[$i]['options'] = json_encode($options);
            }
        }

        $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

This is the picture once the page loads and we select the checkout address:
[image]

This is the image where we have proceeded to select the address and went to the next step and the page reloaded.

[image]

Comment: This is attribute option. right? If yes then modify the option directly from attribute options section.

Comment: @SukumarGorai We are aware of the feature, but we can not modify all product attributes because of the huge quantity of products there are. We could do it through database, but it's not an option either because we use a synchro which checks if there are changes in products and automatically uploads the changes.